# Getting widths of columns in a row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a column system for my website and its going to look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-13">a</div>
        <div class="col-13" style="background-color: yellow;">a</div>
        <div class="col-13">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where it in CSS looks like:

```
.container {
    width: 75%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.col-13 {
    width: 33.333333%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Now I am trying to create a simple system in jQuery, when a `<div class="row">` with columns in it (`<div class="col-13"> etc. etc. etc.`) its `width` is more then 100%. The row is not displaying.

So first I had to find all all widths of the columns inside the row. Which I tried by this piece of code:

```
$('.row div[class*="col-"]').each(function(index) {
   var _this = $(this);
   var width = _this.width();
   var parentWidth = _this.offsetParent().width();
   var percent = Math.round(100*width/parentWidth);
   console.log('The elements width is '+percent+'%');
});
```

But when I tried it with this html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-13">a</div>
    <div class="col-13" style="background-color: yellow;">a</div>
    <div class="col-13">a</div>
</div>
```

**Expected output**
3x `33.333333%`, Because I have 3x an element of `<div class="col-13">` which has an `width` of `33.333333%`.

**Actual output**
3x `25%`, I guess because the `.container` has a width of `75%` and its counting up that, but I don't know why.

After that I want to calculate it, but I have no idea how to do that.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mbzj7/)**

Comment: sorry, i think i was in dumb land when i commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var parentWidth = _this.offsetParent().width();
```

to

```
var parentWidth = _this.parent().width();
```

This is because [offsetParent()](http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/) will search the ancestors for the first positioned ancestor. In your example, this will return the `html` element as far as I can see.

[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), without a specified selector, will return the closest parent element. In your example, this will return `.row`.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but it works :D thank you. Didnt know that.